# javascript html not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, google-chrome

I am working on this code to display the list of clients and onclick it populate the text field with the selected name and the hidden text field for the id.

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="" />
<input type="text" name="client" id="client" class="round full-width-input" value="Type a name..." onChange="searchClient()" onkeypress="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();" onfocus="if(this.value=='Type a name...') {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Type a name...'; document.getElementById('search_results').innerHTML = '';}" />
<label style="margin:0 0 0 1%"><i id="search_results"></i></label>
```

Onchange it uses javascript to call a php file.

Javascript

```
function searchClient()
{
    var str = document.getElementById("client").value;
    if (str == "")
       {
           document.getElementById("search_results").innerHTML = "";
           return;
       } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {
           // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
            document.getElementById("search_results").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","search_client.php?name="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

The php file is returning the list and populates the label. Below is whats returning from PHP file

```
echo '<a onClick="selectClient('.$fullname.','.$row[0].')">
<tr><td class="cap">'.$fullname.'</td></tr></a>';
```

Then I can click on the list and it call javascript again to populate the text field.

Javascript selectClient

```
function selectClient(name,id)
{
    document.getElementById("id").value = id;
    document.getElementById("client").value = name;
    document.getElementById("search_results").innerHTML = "";
}
```

My problem is:
This is not working on Chrome, but works nicely IE.
Anyone knows what am I missing here?

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you're using jQuery why are you using the longhand AJAX method of XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this and put your `<a>` into the `<td>`

```
echo '<tr><td class="cap">
      <a onClick="selectClient(\''.$fullname.'\',\''.$row[0].'\')">'.$fullname.'</a>
      </td></tr>';
```

Comment: <a> tag in <tr> possible?

Comment: WRONG WRONG WRONG. Your answer has the same exact problem as the OP has.

Comment: Nothing like changing your answer... ;)

Answer (score 3):

That is INVALID html. You can not have an anchor tag wrapped around a TR.

Add the onclick to the TR and get rid of the anchor, or move the anchor inside the td.

Comment: I'd stick with your final suggestion to keep the anchor, because anchors work from the keyboard. Click handlers on elements that don't have a built-in click behaviour are an accessibility fail...

Answer (score 0):

You can not have an `<a>` tag in `<tr>`. So try in Onclick of a `<tr>`

Try with this

```
echo '<tr><td onClick="selectClient('.$fullname.','.$row[0].')" class="cap">'.$fullname.'</td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think anchor tag you mentioned in your code is the problem correct it and

Echo the value then you will get a clear idea about it.

Comment: So your answer to the OP's problem is that they should "correct it"? Could you be a bit more specific please?